# Knitr: Do not purl a chunk

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

Consider the following `test.Rmd`:

````
```{r setup, purl=FALSE}
opts_chunk$set(purl=FALSE)
opts_template$set(nopurl = list(purl=FALSE))
```     

```{r test1}
print(1)
```

```{r test2, opts.label='nopurl'}
print(2)
```

```{r test3, purl=FALSE}
print(3)
```
````

`purl('test.Rmd')` gives `test.R`, where none of the test* chunks is supposed to be purled, but:

```
## ----test1---------------------------------------------------------------
print(1)


## ----test2, opts.label='nopurl'------------------------------------------
print(2)
```

Only `test3` is not purled, the rest are purled, despite the global option     `opts_chunk$set(purl=FALSE)` and the label `nopurl`.
Why?

Comment: Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: @Thomas: agree, hopefully Yihui will read here and settle the doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Yihui feedback, the way to go is like follows:

````
```{r setup, purl=FALSE}
knit_hooks$set(purl = hook_purl)
opts_template$set(nopurl = list(purl=FALSE))
opts_template$set(dopurl = list(purl=TRUE))
```

```{r test}
print(1)
```

```{r test2, opts.label='nopurl'}
print(2)
```

```{r test3, opts.label='dopurl'}
print(3)
```
````

With this approach, you don't need to:

```
purl('test.Rmd')
```

You simply:

```
knit('test.Rmd')
```

and get both the  usual `test.md` and the `test.R` file.  The latter is as follows:

```
## ----test----------------------------------------------------------------
print(1)

## ----test3, opts.label='dopurl'------------------------------------------
print(3)
```

As you see, given `knit_hooks$set(purl = hook_purl)`, the default behaviour for chunks is purling.

In actual use `nopurl` and `dopurl` will collect more options to be set together with (no-)purling.
Anyway, when considering the following note:

> N.B. There is no guarantee that the R script generated by 'purl()'
>   can reproduce the computation done in 'knit()'. The 'knit()'
>   process can be fairly complicated (special values for chunk
>   options, custom chunk hooks, computing engines besides R, and the
>   'envir' argument, etc). If you want to reproduce the computation
>   in a report generated by 'knit()', be sure to use 'knit()',
>   instead of merely executing the R script generated by 'purl()'.
>   This seems to be obvious, but some people just do not get it.

it seems wise to always use  `knit_hooks$set(purl = hook_purl)` and set the `purl=FALSE` when purl is not needed.

Comment: The problem is adding `opts.label` if it's not there already requires just as much typing as adding `purl = FALSE`, and is less transparent

Comment: I find this extremely convoluted way about getting a fairly basic thing accomplished. to accomplish one thing one needs: `knit_hooks$set`, `opts_templates$set` x2 ! and then `opts.label`. And it's not at all clear `hook_purl` comes from.

Comment: I just tested this. In order for there to be a default such that a chunk is automatically purled, one must delete the line: `opts_template$set(dopurl = list(purl=TRUE))`

Answer (score 2):

It is not a bug, but just that `purl()` does not executed any code chunks, so the first code chunk was not really executed. The `purl()` function is not reliable in many ways, and see `?knitr::hook_purl` instead. That said, I'd not recommend purling a document at all; knitting is more reliable (See the Note section in `?knitr::purl`).

Comment: Okay, this is informative and makes sense on one level. I'm confused, though, about why `purl` is even an option at all, then. I don't really see how that is useful.

Comment: @Thomas It is there for historical reasons (literate programming, weave, tangle, and all that). Now I find it not useful at all.